# Redirecting a client's request to a second server to get it served and back to the first server

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

There is a website hosted on server A. This host is a shared host with limited capabilities. Then, there is a second server which is dedicated and has all required functionalities and capabilities.

I want to redirect the client request as is, to the second server, to get it served, processed, and then send back the required information back to the server one. Here is the scenario:

1- User send a request for www.site.com
2- www.site.com receives the request, send the client information to the second server with a different domain, for instance mysecondsite.com, and the receives some packs of data.
3- site.com renders the page (or serve the request) with the data returned from mysecondsite.com

This probably should be done with APACHE since I need the request to be sent before the PHP's processing, since I want some certain raw information to be sent.

Now, for those who might be curious why I should do this?

As you know, I install extension or tools which does certain things which shared-hosting never install or allow. I have a dedicated server which is optimized by many tools and extensions.
For instance, assume that I have written a PHP extension which serves the user request and provide an array of information about its agents, versions, operating systems etc.  Using the scenario above, I then send back information information from my dedicated server back to the request's source server.

The example above is only feasible if the host be dedicated. Which in many cases of my clients, is not.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar and used curl for it:

```
    $url = "http://secondserver.com?p=SOMESECRET";

    $post['data[expire]'] = '2014-07-04';
    $post['data[date]']= date("d.m.Y", time());
    $post['data[count]']= $data['count'];

    //initialize session
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    //the generated pdf from the external server
    $tmppdf = tempnam($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/cache/","pdf");
    $fp = fopen($tmppdf, "a+b");

    //session options
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post); 
    //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);

    //execute the request
    curl_exec($ch);

    //close the session and filepointer
    curl_close($ch);
    fclose($fp);
```

and on the server second server side:

```
    $privateKey = "SOMESECRET";
    if($privateKey != $_GET['p']) return;

    $yourPassedData = $_POST['data'];
```

and you are done.

Additional:

If you want to serve directly the response from another server you can use the following combination:

```
    $post['data[headers]'] = getallheaders();

    //initialize session
    $ch = curl_init($url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$post); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
```

for the part where you want to fetch the request header, please refer to:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.getallheaders.php

Comment: Though your solution really comes handy in many situation, but in some special situations I need the request to be served by my optimized PHP, which means I need to pass request from apache of first server to the PHP's of second server (which is optimized), since PHP's of first server is short of required extensions/functions

Comment: Ok, i think i understand your question. You want to analyze the requested http header and send the corresponding response from your optimized server.

Maybe you can pass your headers as payload to the other server and process the stuff there?

Comment: I need more explanation from your side. Can you edit your answer? Also there is some consideration of mod_proxy

Comment: I'll add some more information how you get the response from the other server.

The advantage of not using mod_proxy is, that you can process some data on your local server before you pass the request to the second server.

If you want to use mod_proxy, you have to configure apache on the first server, which isn't possible either on most of the shared hosting providers.

Answer (score 0):

I think Apache's mod_rewrite module does not work in this scenario, because you cannot forward to another domain without making it visible to the client.

However, you could
simply

- receive the request on the first server
- use PHP's `file_get_contents()` function, using a URL including all the information that is necessary for the special request
- parse the request on the second server and echo the response e.g. in JSON format
- parse the response of the request on the first server

Instead if `file_get_contents()`, you could also use PHP's cURL (if available on the first server), since it is more flexible and offers more possibilities.

Comment: could you elaborate more? what to do with file_get_contents?

Comment: Well, actually, I would recommend the CURL version (see other answer), but concerning `file_getContents()`: www.site1.com receives a request, which calls a PHP script. In the PHP script, you collect the appropriate information from the request and generate a new URL to the second server, e.g. `$result = json_decode(file_get_contents(www.site2.com/jsonrequest/?a=b&c=d&so=on));`. (You can only do GET requests with this method. For POST requests, you definitely need CURL.)